# JQuery Mobile and navbar buttons

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a JQuery Mobile application. This application has a navbar in the footer as detailed here: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0.1/docs/toolbars/docs-navbar.html.

The oddity is, and maybe this is just JQM, but it seems odd that each navbar button links to its own page. It seems like you would want to have the option to link to views in a page so you could have one instance of the navbar. In addition, the navigation animation seems odd. My question is;

1) Is there a clean way to write a single page that has a single navbar? When a user clicks a navbar button, I want to show them a view within the current page instead of redirecting them to a separate page.

2) Is there a way to turn OFF the animation? In the case of a navbar, it seems like you wouldn't want an animation. The iPhone doesn't have a animation when you click the navbar in its native apps.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) jQuery Mobile 1.1 (due out sometime in the next few months) will have fixed toolbars which might resolve your issue:
http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2012/01/10/upcoming-releases-1-0-1-1-1-and-beyond/

2) You can set animations on a link by link basis, or globally using the config options
http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0.1/docs/api/globalconfig.html
(look for "defaultPageTransition")

Comment: Thanks for insights. I sincerely appreciate it.